# Why the scrollbar thumb moving to the starting position while leaving the thumb after dragging?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar

I have created a custom control for having the scrolling support. This control consist of two scrollbars namely HScollBar and VScrollBar. 
When i drag and leave the thumb at the particular location, it moves to the starting location(0).

[image]

How can i prevent the thumb moving to the default position and is there any easy way to achieve the custom scroll control using the scrollbars?

Comment: You don't need to use scrollbars for scrolling. You can set `AutoScroll` to `true`. Also if your control is a custom paint control, set `AutoScrollMinSize` to a suitable value. For a normal container control, you don't need to manipulate `AutoScrollMinSize` yourself, it will be calculated based on locations of child controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use scrollbars for scrolling. You can set `AutoScroll` to `true`. Also if your control is a custom paint control, set `AutoScrollMinSize` to a suitable value. For a normal container control, you don't need to manipulate `AutoScrollMinSize` yourself, it will be calculated based on locations of child controls. For example:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AutoScroll = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //for a custom paint control, calculate the minimum size which needs scrollbars
        //for a normal container control you don't need to calculate minimum size
        this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(300, 500); 
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var r = this.DisplayRectangle;
        r.Width--; r.Height--;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, r);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Top-Left", Font, r, ForeColor, 
            TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Bottom-Right", Font, r, ForeColor, 
            TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.Right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, My intention is to create a custom control that allows to customize the scrollbars both vertical and horizontal.

Comment: You're welcome, Copy and paste the code in a class in your application and after building the solution, then from toolbox, drop `UserControll1` to your form. Run the application and see the result.

Comment: The solution allows you to set the minimum value for scrolling for both width and height. So you can make the control to show one of scrollbars, both of them or none of them.

Comment: Its working charm, how can i replace the default scrollbars with the custom one. for example, i need to show the office2007 scrollbars instead of the default one.

Comment: Take a look at [How to skin scrollbars for Panels, in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C).